# Self hosted user feedback options

Tags: feedback, usability-testing, user-feedback

Our product requires us to self-host whatever tools we use for information privacy. If our on-site lawyers do not approve a tool or service, we cannot use it.

I have been tasked with coming up with analytics and user feedback solutions for our UX team. I have had great success in the past using Usabilla Live and Crazy Egg. What are some self-hosted solutions that would provide the same functionality?

So far I have only found Piwik (piwik.org), but am looking for other options. What tools have you had success using (if any) for remote user feedback like Usabilla?

Comment: Google docs -> form to spreadsheet can work in a pinch.

Comment: Google docs are not hosted on-site.

Comment: How big of a team will be working with the data?  How important is it to have great UI and tooling?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this depends on if you are bringing users on-site or not, but have you looked at Morae (http://www.techsmith.com/morae.html)?

Some things to keep in mind about it:

- It's best for when you don't a ton of users (e.g. < 20)
- It's good for getting both qualitative data as well as quantitative data
- If all you want is Google Analytics style data, it probably will require a good amount of work to get there
- That said, it does collect a surprising amount of info (e.g. mouse clicks, time on task)
- There is a kiosk mode (I forget the exact name) that allows you to set up tasks and not have to be at the computer
- I believe you can have the recordings be password-protected
- If the people you are testing are offsite, then this solution won't work unless you string it through webEx, etc. (but you'll lose some data that way)

For more GA-like solutions, I've heard good things about Mint (http://haveamint.com/).

Also, if you're just testing specific types of interactions, many CMSes have analytics packages--a good example to this is WordPress, which has a bunch of different analytics plugins.

Hope this helps.